# Golang GORM Delete with Select

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to cascade delete the below structure:

```
type Action struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string
    Email string
    Halls []Hall `gorm:"foreignKey:ActionID"`
}

type Hall struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string
    ActionID uint
    Stream   Stream  `gorm:"foreignKey:HallID"`
}

type Stream struct {
    ID     uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    HallID uint
    Name   string
}
```

`db.Select("Halls").Delete(&action)` - works fine for selected `action` and with all related `halls`.

How can I delete this one and related `streams`?
Something like:

```
db.Select("Halls", "Streams").Delete(&action)  
db.Select("Streams").Select("Halls").Delete(action)
```

doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it is going to affect the nested `Stream` models, but you can try `db.Select("Halls.Stream").Delete(&action)` or `db.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&action)`

Comment: @EminLaletovic it won't work. I'm not sure whether what the OP wants is possible with soft delete. Without it, a simple `constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE` would solve it.

Answer (score 0):

- you can not use delete and select at same time in same query means it not feasible solution to do that
  but yeah you can use this [reference link](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Specify-Struct-search-fields)
- Try Deleting action with where condition and specify HallID

> db.Where("hall_id IN ?",**HallID**).Delete(&action)

and SET HallID to `constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE` in Stream so when you delete Halls then automatically Streams will be deleted whichever associated with that Halls

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on M_x so I'll put this as an answer.

You are allowed to 'Delete' with 'Select' with associations.  See https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select

However, I'm also looking for a solution for nested associations where the nested is a slice of a struct.

Comment: any luck in delete nested child when it's a slice?